# Laravel and what it can be used for?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I would like to know exactly what Laravel is used for in terms of development.

For example can i use Laravel for ANY project where i use PHP?
eg:    From a Simple Landing Page with Authentication to SPA or major projects for example text based game.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Laravel is a php framework based on symphony framework. It offers developers comfort on writing codes. It can be used in any php projects including Simple Landing Page to full fledged application and text based games. Just think it as a toolbox provided for us to get developing job easier rather than just scrap materials. Also, don't forget we have other frameworks too like Yii2, Phalcon PHP, CodeIgniter etc. It is upto your taste, whichever you want to use depending on certain scenarios of your project.

Comment: Ah thats good to know, i am still learning the concept of laravel workflow though. Initially i just wrote core php.

Answer (score 0):

You can build very light applications as huge complex projects as well. Just keep in mind that Laravel (and especially its older versions) is quite slow, so my advice if you need to build a light application is to use Lumen instead.

http://lumen.laravel.com/

Lumen derives from Laravel framework but is lighter and faster. It is almost thought for little app and API.

Comment: If i am going to provide a scalable project to a client then is lumen still viable? You say laravel is slow compared to lumen, how so?

Comment: Hi Elevant, have a look at this link http://taylorotwell.com/how-lumen-is-benchmarked/ You can see some benchmark tests done by Taylor Otwell himself. Lumen is easily scalable to Laravel without any problem, I have already done it a couple of times, even if I must admit that there is few documentation about this issue.